# Open Atrium 2: comment forms not appearing on pages

Tags: nodes, comments, distributions

**Situation:**

- Recently created a fresh Open Atrium 2 installation to replace an old AO1.
- No content from the old OA1 database has been migrated, we're making a fresh start. Some content (a few pages) will be recreated by copy-pasting the content.
- No anonymous access allowed, only authenticated users have acces to any content. Only admins can create user accounts.
- As of yet, no groups and teams have been made -- there's only a handful of users. The actual userbase will be small enough that it can be managed simply by giving individuals access to certain spaces; groups and teams may be made later if the need arises. (I'm still partially in OA1 mode, really :) )

---

**Problem:** Comment forms do not appear anywhere in the site, for any user level (authenticated, editor, admin).

---

**I have:**

- checked whether the required comment modules are enabled (they are)
- checked permissions; authenticated users can view & post comments, skip approval & edit their own comments
- made sure commenting is enabled for that content type (it is by default, no settings changed there)
- made sure it's not simply a matter of permissions not being retroactive. Newly created content still has the same problem, though.
- checked individual nodes (in this case, calendar events) to make sure comments are open
- spent several hours googling, but found nothing beyond the things I've already tried.

---

Most likely I'm simply overlooking one little setting somewhere, but right now this has me stumped... Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add the comment box via panels. Admin > Configuration > Content Authoring > Panelizer > Content [link to the right of Your Content Type]